# Magento migration from localhost to cloud server - local.xml mySQL issue

Tags: magento-1.9, error, mysql, migration, localhost

I am migrating a Magento installation (1.9.2) from my localhost to my cloud server on Digital Ocean.

Here is where I am at:
(I copied some of these steps from another thread)

- zipped and transferred all files from localhost to cloud server
- imported the mysql database
- edited the app/etc/local.xml to connect to the cloud mySQL DB
- tweaked core_config_data table in phpmyadmin and replaced 2 values with new URL (IP address)
- cleared var/cache, var/session, var/report, var/log
- checked all file and folder permissions.

(I have removed my server IP address for privacy)

After all that I receive the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:78:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '111.222.333.444' (111)";i:1;s:1511:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
/var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
/var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
/var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
/var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup')
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
/var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/var/www/html/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Here is my local.xml file (IP Address edited):

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Thu, 26 Nov 2015 20:09:46 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[5c83b31252cb9b042055a802b2d3dbdf]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[111.222.333.444]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento_ultimo]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the setup, teh configuration does not look wrong. Does the database `magento_ultimo` actually exist?

Comment: Hi,I managed to quickly find the issue. 

The IP address was not needed in the local.xml file. I simply reverted the `IP address` to say `localhost`...and it worked.

Well..it showed me my shopfront in a very mutated form, lacking all formatting/CSS/anything - I think there are some template issues from the migration :/

Comment: On a related note, I now a 404 error on all pages, however I do see some of the page text content (badly formatted menu items and product fields...) however the overall page template is missing as well as all formatting styling and images. 

Any idea, what could be going on? It seems like all magento folders have been copied correctly..

Thanks,
Damien

Comment: make sure, `var` and `media` are writable by the webserver user and that URL rewrites are enabled

Comment: Thanks @fschmengler. I checked those directories. All good.
Two more symptoms  (1) The headers and footers seem to be rendering fine on all pages (2) I am unable to access the Magento Admin console as I see the same 404 error page (that looks like my storefront)...so possibly there is a URL redirect issue? or an attribute that I missed?
Any thoughts?  Many thanks!

Comment: ok...problem solved..there was on additional attribute in the `core_config_data` table named `base_link_url` that was not correct. I didn't modify this after installation, so I'm not sure what happened. Anyway, I changed the value from `{{unsecure_base_url}}/magento/` to `{{unsecure_base_url}}` and all seems to be ok. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, the shopfront appears fine now. The final issue is that I am uanble to login to the admin console. Even when I reset the password via mySQL or myphpadmin...I am still unable to login.  I have been reading that this could be a 'cookies' issue...any thoughts?
Also - just a quick reminder to readers that this issue came about after a migration from a localhost magento instance to a cloud server.  Many thanks in advance!